# Can't make Lambda function work in react-native with aws-amplify, can someone help me?

Tags: node.js, react-native, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-amplify

Okay, so after 5 hours trying to find a solution myself I tought it was time to look for some help.

So I followed this tutorial to create a REST api, and attach a lambda function to it: https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/build-a-backend/restapi/set-up-rest-api/

I choose the name "NearalizeREST" for my api, and the name "StripeHandler" for my function, my directory now looks like this:

[Amplify directory after adding api and function using amplify cli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i88Qf.png)

I edited the code inside my function, and deployed my new api using the "amplify push" command, after doing that, the API in the console looks like this, everything seems to be set up correctly:

[Deployed API in AWS Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJSSL.png)

However after following this tutorial: https://docs.amplify.aws/react-native/prev/build-a-backend/restapi/fetch-data/

I edited the code in my react-native app to look like this:

```
import { API } from 'aws-amplify';

const fetchPaymentSheetParams = async () => {
try {
console.log("began function successfully");
const response = await API.post('NearalizeREST', '/stripehandler', {
body: {},
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
},
});
console.log("response obtained: " + response);
const {clientSecret, customer} = await response.json();

return {
clientSecret,
customer,
};
} catch (error) {
console.error("Error fetching payment sheet params: ", error);
// Handle the error appropriately
}
  };
```

If I understand correctly the first parameter "API.post" should receive are the name of the API and the path to my function. However, whenever I run that code I get this error in the log:

As you can see, the first log is executed, meaning the function started executing, however the second long displaying the response is not. Meaning the error indicates the URL could not even be found. The problem doesn't seem to be with the code inside the function, but rather with the deployment and/or calling of the function itself.

[Console logs when running the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84x7w.png)

I'm not sure what I did wrong, I followed the docs step by step and I can't find any source with the same problem.

I tried to create a REST API in AWS amplify, and call a lambda function using that API.
I was expecting the API call to return a response.